# Extract domain name from HTML tag in Google SHeets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column in google sheet that contains text like below

```
<a href="javascript:openPopupFocus%28%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rockemsocks.com%27%2C%20%27_blank%27%2C%20620%2C%20430%2C%20%27width%3D620%2Cheight%3D430%2Cresizable%3Dyes%2Ctoolbar%3Dyes%2Cstatus%3Dyes%2Cscrollbars%3Dyes%2Cmenubar%3Dyes%2Cdirectories%3Dyes%2Clocation%3Dyes%2Cdependant%3Dno%27%2C%20false%2C%20true%29%3B" title="http://www.rockemsocks.com (New Window)">http://www.rockemsocks.com</a>
```

I wanted to extract only the domain name that is within `<a href="blah blah">` and `</a>`. Is there an easier approach to pull this information?

Answer (score 0):

All of the text string in your example is either:

- html tag, or
- the string of the needed url

Here separated onto three lines:

```
<a href="javascript:openPopupFocus%28%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.snipped.example.com">
http://www.rockemsocks.com
</a>
```

As you noted, removing the html tags would leave the url. Several formulas could do this. Here's an example using REGEXREPLACE to get the url from A1:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"<[^>]+>","")
```

In English, it looks for `<`
followed by any characters that are not `>`
followed by a `>`
and replaces matches with an empty string `""`

To apply it to a whole column, it could be wrapped in an arrayformula, be made to skip blank input cells, and be given as input instead now a reference to the whole source column. Here, say if you have one header row, K2 could contain the formula to pull in data starting in J2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(LEN(J2:J)),"",REGEXREPLACE(J2:J,"<[^>]+>","")))
```